# How to disable "Send me new responses to my posts via email"?

Tags: support

I accidentally pressed the "Send me new responses to my posts via email" checkbox above the <kbd>Post your answer</kbd> button and posted an answer. I would like to disable this. However,I cannot find a button to disable this. So,How to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your profile, click preferences, and uncheck it from there.

[image]